# Parallelism in RxJava - Filter

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

I have some pretty simple code, read a bunch of Strings & apply a filter. I expected the filter to run on multiple threads.

```
    Iterable<String> outputs = Observable
            .from(Files.readLines(new File("E:\\SAMA\\Test\\ImageNetBullets.txt"), Charset.forName("utf-8")))
            .take(20).subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadPoolExecutor)).filter(str -> isURLOK(str))
            .toBlocking().toIterable();
```

From the logs, it seems that the Filter method is running on just 1 thread:

```
In Thread pool-1-thread-1
In Thread pool-1-thread-1
http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1258/1479683334_3ff920d217.jpg
In Thread pool-1-thread-1
In Thread pool-1-thread-1
```

How do I speed it up?

Comment: RxJava is sequential by nature, you have to add paralellism manually via `flatMap` for example.

Comment: that statement ... doesnt make any sense - even the title of ReactiveX contains "asynchronous". In fact its easy to **choose** between sequential, singlethreaded execution and asynchronous, parallel - apparently `Observable` seems to be the right choice for parallel as can be seen [in the intro](https://reactivex.io/intro.html), even. What you actually meant was this : the above example shows iterative, sequential execution in the sense of a stream which is read sequentially, RxJava makes it possible to split the entire dataset into many Observables and back into a single, parallel one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RxJava is sequential by nature. For example, using `map(Func1)`, the `Func1` itself will be executed non-concurrently with the values passing through the parent sequence:

```
Observable.range(1, 10).map(v -> v * v).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Here, the lambda v -> v * v will be called with values 1 thru 10 in a sequential manner.

RxJava can be asynchronous in the manner that stages in a pipeline (range->map->subscribe) can happen concurrently/parallel relative to each other. For example:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.map(v -> v * v)                       // (1)
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(v -> -v)                          // (2)
.toBlocking()
.subscribe(System.out::println);       // (3)
```

Here, (1) may run in parallel with (2) and (3), i.e., while (2) calculates a v = 3 * 3, (1) may already calculate v = 5 and (3) is printing out `-1` at the same time.

In case you want to process elements of the sequence concurrently, you have to "fork out" the sequence into sub-`Observable`s, then join back the results with `flatMap`:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
.flatMap(v -> 
    Observable.just(v)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .map(v -> v * v)
)
.toBlocking()
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Here, each value `v` will start a new `Observable` that runs on a background thread and computes via map() there. `v = 1` may run on the thread 1, `v = 2` may run on thread 2, `v = 3` may run on thread 1 but strictly after `v = 1` has been computed.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The call to `.subscribeOn` just determines what `Scheduler` the observable will be initiated on (and for your example all emissions will travel on the one thread provided by the scheduler).

If you don't have much work to do with each item in the stream then the processing may be dominated by IO and thus parallel processing may not help.

Generally speaking though one approach is to buffer the stream into chunks and process each chunk within a `flatMap` that is subscribed on `Schedulers.computation()`:

```
 Observable<String> outputs = 
   lines
    .buffer(1000)
    .flatMap(list -> 
        Observable
          .from(list)
          //do something computationally expensive
          .filter(line -> intensive(line))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()));
```

The `buffer` is used because there's less overhead to schedule decent chunks of work than scheduling lots of tiny tasks.